# Any reason why ng-repeat-start doesn't work despite using the latest angularJS version?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Does anyone know why ng-repeat-start doesn't work despite using the latest version of AngularJS?

I'm importing it form the CDN:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
```

Then, when I do:

```
<li ng-repeat-start="phone in phones">
   blabblah
</li>
<li ng-repeat-end="">
   more blahblah
</li>
```

it doesn't work, but when i just do

```
<li ng-repeat="phone in phones">
  blahblah
</li>
```

it works again!

Does anyone know why? I've been gnawing at this problem for days, and I just can't find the answer. Can anyone help me?

Comment: please, post your code

Comment: please share the code you have so far

Comment: sry, but be more specific. Any real code example would be nice instead of *blahblah*

Comment: You mispelled the first "blah", I think this is the problem, assuming you are using the right version of *blahblah*

Comment: sorry guys, I was still editing the post just now, that's why the code wasn't showing. can you please help me re-upvote it since now the code is up? thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @HongyiLi Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you get any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: @DotDotDot: the 'blahblah' was just a filler, so I was assuming that angularJS should render the first block and the second block the same number of times. However, it wasn't the case, and I was forced to use ng-repeat (without the ng-repeat-start) which only allows repetition of a single code block

Comment: @JezenThomas: Nope I didn't get any javascript errors in the console

Comment: @HongyiLi you're using the wrong version of angular, try with 1.2.0-rc.2 You can check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/bS2LP/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Versions problem. AngularJS version 1.0.8 dont support `ng-repeat-start` or `ng-repeat-end`.

Upgrade to `1.2.0-rc.2`.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem. I thought 1.0.8 was the newest one because it was the latest stable one provided by angular. thanks again @CodeHater